# Texture doesn't show up after UV wrapping

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, uv

I have made a model, UV mapped it and made a UV image, but it doesn't show up on the actual model. I feel like I'm doing everything right, and don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Blender version is 2.77. 
[image]